# relaxed Security AppiumService

Tags: c#, appium, appium-android

I am new to Appium, and I want to execute some ADB commands using appium with C#,
example to execute "adb shell ps"

```
Dictionary<string, object> map = new Dictionary<string, object>();
map.Add("command", "ps");
var output = driverAndroid.ExecuteScript("mobile: shell", map);
```

And I start appium programatically

```
AppiumLocalService service;
AppiumServiceBuilder builder;
if (service == null)
{
   builder = new 
   AppiumServiceBuilder().WithLogFile(new System.IO.FileInfo("Log"));
   service = builder.Build();
}

if (!service.IsRunning)
{
   service.Start();
}
service.Start();
```

So an exception raised and it says to run appium with relaxed Security.
I try running appium by command line with this "appium --relaxed-security" and it works.
I try to check this [link](https://appiumpro.com/editions/3) 

I think I need to add an argument but I don't know which one.

```
OptionCollector args = new OptionCollector().AddArguments(GeneralOptionList.);
```

So how  to start appium with relaxed security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After digging, I find that this feautre can't run programatically on appium.
So I run appium in command line like this **appium --relaxed-security**
and from that, I can run adb commands using appium.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Appium desktop, go to advanced and check the "relaxed security" checkbox.