# Log Appium testresults to console

Tags: c#, testing, logging, appium, appium-desktop

Appium won't log the test results (of the UI-tests, executed with adb emulator) to the debug output (Deug.WriteLine).

According to the documentation, get test logs is possible with the following line

```
ILogs logs = driver.Manage().Logs;
```

Hower, Appium has different log types:

- Browser
- Client
- Driver
- Profiler
- Server

I tried every single log type with the following code. But by executing I don't get any result and the test will (where I put the code) fail. Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

```
ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
//  ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Client);
//  ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Driver);
//  ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Profiler);
//  ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Server);

foreach (var log in logs)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Time: " + log.Timestamp);
    Debug.WriteLine("Message: " + log.Message);
    Debug.WriteLine("Level: " + log.Level);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure out.

1. Check this article first
   [relaxed Security AppiumService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858703/relaxed-security-appiumservice)
2. Get the log type

   ```
       IReadOnlyCollection<string> logTypes = driver.Manage().Logs.AvailableLogTypes;
       foreach (string logType in logTypes)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(logType);
           //logcat
           //bugreport
           //server
       }
   ```
3. Print logs

   ```
   public static void PrintLogs(string logType)
   {
       try
       {
           ILogs _logs = driver.Manage().Logs;
           var browserLogs = _logs.GetLog(logType);
           if (browserLogs.Count > 0)
           {
               foreach (var log in browserLogs)
               {
                   //log the message in a file
                   Console.WriteLine(log);
               }
           }
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           //There are no log types present
           Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
       }
   ```

[Picture : C# Console Print appium log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUwf6.jpg)

Comment: Thank you! I noticed that they have updated the documentation.

Comment: No worries, mate

Answer (score -1):

In java I am doing it using the following code:

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
for (LogEntry logEntry : logEntries) {
        System.out.println(logEntry);
}
```

Not sure if this method works for C#. Please give it a try

```
List<LogEntry> logEntries = _driver.Manage().Logs().Get("logcat").GetAll();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried:  ReadOnlyCollection<LogEntry> logs = _driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog("logcat"); but the test fails again. What does the log look like in java?

Comment: It will show the log that we get while running **adb devices** command. What do you mean by test fail?

Comment: When I try to log the results to the debug output the test will fail with the message: 'System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'. If I remove that specific code (to log the results) the test succeeds.

Comment: Can you replace ReadOnlyCollection with List and try if it is showing the same error?

Comment: please check [List](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/codeeditor?cid=cs-At1qDb) to learn how to use list in c#

Comment: I know how to use lists in C#. But the GetLog method returns a ReadOnlyCollection of LogEntries. Link: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ILogs_GetLog.htm